# Accessing the window object in Firefox addon content script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can't seem to access the window object in a content script. Is this normal?

For example, this does nothing:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello from the onload");
};
```

Instead, I have to use the `unsafeWindow` object.

```
unsafeWindow.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello from the onload");
};
```

I must be missing something simple right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `window.onload`, instead write:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("Hello from the onload");
}, false);
```

`window.onload` has the limitation that there can only be one event listener, setting a different listener replaces the existing one - that's already a reason why you should never use it. In case of the Add-on SDK things get more complicated because the content script has a different view of the DOM then the web page. So just use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Oh, and please don't use `unsafeWindow` - it is (as the name already says) inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 5):

The window object available to you in a content script is actually a proxy - hence unsafeWindow works and window does not. I did some tests and document.addEventListener does not work either:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/150362/latest/

jQuery seems to work fine though, I imagine there is some magic they do to ensure that they fire no matter what.

The workaround is simply set contentScriptWhen to 'end' and run your code immediately - this should always work as the content script is attached when the document is finished loading.

I did log this bug regarding what I like to think of as the 'wtf?' aspect of this behaviour - I think the result is surprising to web developers and we should try to be less surprising:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787063

Comment: Unfortunately there is a related issue. `window.onbeforeunload` or `window.onunload` can't be accessed either and `$(window).bind('onbeforeunload', fn)` doesn't work. As far as I can tell there are no workarounds to call a function onunload or onbeforeunload from content scripts. This is what I really need to be able to do, I kinda simplified my question to keep it short (doh!).

Comment: I can make a new SO question, file a Moz bug report, make an example etc. Whatever you need.

Comment: Of course `document.addEventListener` doesn't work - it's `window.addEventListener`.